# Reuse singleton views such as webView in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I use some JavaScript code in my Android project and I wanted that to be fully loaded and ready to be shared between activities. For that purpose I made a WebView inside a class that Extends Activity and implemented a fragment that uses this webview as it`s view. The fragment looks something like this.

```
public class CalculatorWebViewFragment extends Fragment {

    private Context context;
    public View view;
    private WebView calculatorWebView;


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable final ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AndroidApplication state = ((AndroidApplication) context.getApplicationContext());
        calculatorWebView = state.getCalculatorWebView();

        if (calculatorWebView.getParent() != null) {
            ((ViewGroup) calculatorWebView.getParent()).removeView(calculatorWebView); // <- fix/
        }

        view = calculatorWebView;

        return view;
    }

}
```

And in my activities xml I have something like this

```
<fragment
                android:id="@+id/calculator_web_view_fragment_in_test"
                android:name="com.classcalc.classcalc.fragments.CalculatorWebViewFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/topBarFragmentContainer"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/topBarFragmentContainer"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/topBarFragmentContainer"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/topBarFragmentPlaceHolder" />
```

The only issue that I have is that if some of my activities are displaying other activity that uses this fragment, when I go back to my previous activity(where the activity is not recreated) the fragment shows up as a blank screen. I am assuming this is because the sub activity called the onCreateView method of the fragment, which removes the previous parent of the calculatorWebView.

I tried resetting the fragment in my main activity on resume method by doing something like this

```
frg = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.my_fragment_id);
final FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.detach(frg);
ft.attach(frg);
ft.commit();
```

but it does not seem to solve my problem. How can I fix this issue? Also is this the best way to reuse the same WebView in multiple activities or there is a simpler way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I fix this issue?

- I dont think this issue can be fixed. U cannot have some fragment out side activity life cycle, at least to solve  your purpose. There is something `retainInstance` but will also not solve your problem.

> Also is this the best way to reuse the same WebView in multiple activities or there is a simpler way to achieve this?

- No. you cannot use same webview instance in multiple activities, bad practise too.

But you can use your fragment(containing webview) in all activities as new instance. Use `add` or `replace` in the fragment transaction.

Comment: Thank you for your response Sush. Could you please provide some reasoning as to why it is bad practice to try and reuse the webView instance in multiple activities?

Comment: View instances are linked activities where they reside, one instance cant change its activity once inflated. By somehow if you could able achieve also its against android programming.

Comment: Happy to help you. :-)